# Orphan removal is not working

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jdbc

I need to do the next: when I delete a Parent the childs should be erased as well. I am using the netbeans embedded database and i was reading about this orphanRemoval parameter but is not working for me and i really dont know why.

Parent:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "schema")
public class Pais implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name= "codigo", length=3)
    private String codigo;

    @Column(name= "nombre", length=100)
    private String nombre;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pais", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Estado> estadoLista;
}
```

Child:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "schema")
public class Estado implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name= "codigo", length=3)
    private String codigo;

    @Column(name= "nombre", length=100)
    private String nombre;

    @JoinColumn(name= "id_pais", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private Pais pais;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Estado", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Municipio> municipioLista;
}
```

I really want to be more specific but i already do not understand why does this not working. Just in case i'm including my persistence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="JDCH-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

One more detail, it works the first time I deploy and run the web application but the next tries i get "SQLException statement rolled back."

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified how you are trying to achieve persist/remove operations.
However, basing on info you provided, I have created this simplified example:

Pais class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity (name = "Pais")
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Pais implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column (name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "codigo")
private String codigo;

@Column(name = "nombre")
private String nombre;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "pais", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Estado> estadoLista;

public String create() {
    estadoLista = new ArrayList();
    DataAccess data = new DataAccess();
    Estado estado1 = new Estado("foo", "bar");
    Estado estado2 = new Estado("foofoo", "barbar");
    estadoLista.add(estado1);
    estadoLista.add(estado2);

    Pais pais = new Pais();
    pais.setCodigo("test");
    pais.setNombre("test1");
    pais.setEstadoLista(estadoLista);

    estado1.setPais(pais);
    estado2.setPais(pais);

    data.createPais(pais);
    return "created";
}

public String delete() {
    DataAccess data = new DataAccess();
    Pais pais = data.searchPaisByCodigo("test");
    data.deletePais(pais);

    return "deleted";
}

public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
public Long getId() { return id; }

public void setCodigo(String codigo) { this.codigo = codigo; }
public String getCodigo() { return codigo; }

public void setNombre(String nombre) { this.nombre = nombre; }
public String getNombre() { return nombre; }

public void setEstadoLista(List<Estado> estadoLista) { this.estadoLista = estadoLista; }
public List<Estado> getEstadoLista() { return estadoLista; }
}
```

Estado class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity (name = "Estado")
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Estado implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column (name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "codigo", length=3)
private String codigo;

@Column(name = "nombre", length=100)
private String nombre;

@JoinColumn(name = "id_pais", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne
private Pais pais;

Estado() {}
Estado(String codigo, String nombre) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
public Long getId() { return id; }

public void setCodigo(String codigo) { this.codigo = codigo; }
public String getCodigo() { return codigo; }

public void setNombre(String nombre) { this.nombre = nombre; }
public String getNombre() { return nombre; }

public void setPais(Pais pais) { this.pais = pais; }
public Pais getPais() { return pais; }
}
```

DataAccess class:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public class DataAccess {

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

public void createPais(Pais pais) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(pais);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}

public Pais searchPaisByCodigo(String codigo) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    Query query = em.createQuery("select p from Pais p where p.codigo = :codigo");
    query.setParameter("codigo", codigo);
    Pais result = (Pais)query.getSingleResult();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    return result;
}

public void deletePais(Pais pais) {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(pais);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
}
```

And index.xhtml:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{pais.create}" />
        </h:form>
        <br/>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{pais.delete}" />
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

This code works fine for me.

No need for 'orphanRemoval', since Pais object, after being fetched from the database, already has a list of Estado objects. So, when you remove this Pais object, all associated Estado objects are removed (cascade) as well.

I used Glassfish, JSF 2.2, Toplink and MySQL on Win8.1.

PS. Title of the post is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

@mmalik thanks for your example, i am already using that kind of a model. however the problem was with the persistence

For some weird reason NetBeans wasn't saving the changes on the persistence. so it wasnt saving the following attributes.

```
<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
```

for anything else everthing was right just as observation that if you define `orphanRemoval = true` you should avoid using `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` because its redundant.